# Xcode Timer Profiler: How to view the execution time for each time a function was called vs sum?

Tags: xcode, performance, profiling

I'm looking to evaluate the execution time of a function for different inputs. The Xcode Timer Profiler shows the *total* running time for a specific function, where I would like the time per run.

Options?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have four different inputs. Call them A, B, C, and D.

Call the function one million times in a loop with input A, and simply time it.
You don't need a lot of accuracy.
Then just take the total time in seconds, and that is how much one function execution takes in microseconds, with input A.
If you want nanoseconds, loop it 10^9 times.

Do the same for B, C, and D.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the time window in projections.

Use the time window selection in the graph & see the corresponding call tree in the "detail area" below. Also add flags (view menu > track > add flag ) when  enough accuracy has been achieved.

[image]

- https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/

## Signpost events

If this is not accurate enough, use "Signpost Events" and they'll appear as markings in the Points of Interest instrument graphs to guide you.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2018/07/24/signposts-for-performance-2-instruments/
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/3019241-os_signpost